# how to plot bar chart using plotly with color parameter

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, plotly-python

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['F','F','M','M','M','M','M'],
                     'country':['USA','Belgium','USA','Russia','India','Belgium','Canada'],
                     'count':[123,421,112,445,21,442,226],
                     })

   gender  country     count
0   F       USA         123
1   F     Belgium       421
2   M       USA         112
3   M     Russia        445
4   M     India         21
5   M     Belgium       442
6   M     Canada        226
```

I want to plot a bar char that display the above table using **Plotly** package.
For this i used the code below but it crash and display error:

```
fig = px.histogram(df,x='gender', y='count' ,color =['gender','country'],barmode = 'group')
```

Error:

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 2, whereas the length of previously-processed arguments ['gender', 'count'] is 7

expected output :

[image]

Comment: This post is unclear on the expected output. Can you provide a graphical representation of your final plot?

Comment: i will add a bar chart to my question

Answer (score 2):

Try either:

```
fig = px.histogram(df,x='gender', y='count' ,color ='gender',barmode = 'group')
```

or

```
fig = px.histogram(df,x='gender', y='count' ,color ='country',barmode = 'group')
```

It would also help if you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Your data doesn't make much sense. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve.

EDIT: Your clarification didn't help much, but this may be what you're looking for:

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x='country', y='count', color = 'gender')
```

or based on your picture

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="gender", y="count",color='country', barmode='group')
```

Comment: what i am trying to display a bar chart that combine between the column  that i want to group on with the column or list of columns  which i want to perform aggregation

Comment: what if i had more columns that i want to displayed in the color let say i have a column **age** how to display color combining between `age + gender` in each **country**

Comment: Send a new dataframe.

Comment: thank you for your help i was able to solve it it seems that according to the document  color parameter `color (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to assign color to marks`.
so i create a tuple  and assigned to the `color` parameter

Comment: Could you send your final line(s) of code?

Answer (score 0):

according to the documents color parameter  takes :
**Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object**
for that i create a Series  and assigned to `color`

the code becomes as below:

```
cat = df[['gender','country']].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
fig = px.histogram(df,x=gender, y='count' ,color = cat,barmode = 'group')
```